# MySQL | insertar el ID de una tabla a otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas llamadas *t_Empleado* y *t_Marca*.
En t_Empleado tengo muchos empleados con su id, nombre_empleado etc. Quiero extraer el id de t_Empleado, y colocarlo en la otra tabla t_Marca.creador; es decir que cada vez que agregue un dato en t_Marca el empleado quien a creado el dato se guarde su id para llevar un control de quien agrego el dato.

```
insert into t_Marca(
    id,
    nombre,
    pais,
    correo_electronico,
    categoria,
    descripcion,
    creacion,
    creador -- Aquí quiero agregar el id del empleado quien creo el dato
)
values(
    NULL,
    'Corp',
    'EEUU',
    'Corp@corp.com',
    'PC',
    NULL,
    NOW(),
    t_Empleado.id, -- AQUI QUIERO AGREGAR EL ID DEL EMPLEADO QUIEN A CREADO EL DATO
);
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No tienes que poner id y su valor, si ya lo configuraste como auto incrementable

Comment: Faltan detalles contextuales en tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, ¿qué quiere decir esto y por qué debe ser así: *en la columna creador quiero agregar el id de la tabla t_Empleado automáticamente*? Parecería que esto debe resolverse con un `TRIGGER`, pero es muy confuso pensar que cada vez que se crea un empleado, haya que crear una marca. No sé, es muy raro lo que quieres hacer aquí. ¿Quizá lo que quieres es **normalizar** tus datos? Si explicas mejor el contexto podremos ver el problema con más claridad.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada y estoy totalmente de acuerdo con @A.Cedano

Comment: Relacionalo no más para que puedas agregar la tu idEmpleado

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, buenas tardes. Creo entender la pregunta.
Sin embargo, es difícil saber (con los datos que nos das) de donde estarías tomando el id del empleado. Seguramente lo tengas logeado en tu aplicación y de ahi puedas tomar el dato del ID.
Imagino que en la tabla t_Empleado tendrás muchos (o al menos mas de 1) empleados registrados...
Aquí deberías guardar el ID del empleado cuando inicia sesión (no se en que lenguaje trabajes, pero podría ser una clase en caso de .net o una variable de sesión en caso de PHP...) para luego utilizarlo en el insert que nos mostrás arriba.